# running a nested loop on a list of unknown length

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have defined a list as:

```
comp = []
comp.append(["A", "B", "C", "D"])
comp.append(["E", "F", "I"])
```

In real case, I don't know the length of `comp` or `comp[x]`

Now, I am trying to run a nested loop on this, but failed. What I mean is,
if I run my current snippet:

```
for compsi in range(len(comp)):
  for elemn in range(len(comp[compsi])):
    print(comp[compsi][elemn])
```

the output is `A B C D E F I`.

What I am trying is, for each element of `comp[0]`, the full `comp[1]` will run, so that, I will get:
`A E F I B F I C F I D E F I` and so;

When I know I `len(comp)` = 2, I can easily do this using nested for loop as:

```
for lo in range(len(comp[0])):
  for l1 in range(len(comp[1])):
    print(...)
```

But, how I can achieve the same when I don't know the lenght of `comp`?

Kindly help!

Ok, say, we have `comp=[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['E', 'F', 'G'], ['H'], ['I', 'J','K']]`. We will end up with:

```
A E H I  
A E H J  
A E H K  
A F H I 
...
B E H I 
B E H J 
B E H K
...
D G H K
```

in this way.

Comment: how should look the combination for `len(comp) == 4` ?

Comment: Kindly check the update in OP, as I cant do multiline math mode here

Comment: The first and second example in your post are different. Which one do you want? (Given the logic of the second example and using the input from the first example, the output should be AE, AF, AI, BE, BF, BI,... - this is called the cartesian product)

Comment: recursion on the loop for the next element?

Comment: You are using for loop in the wrong place, also u are using it in a wrong way

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your second given example with the list `[('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), ('E', 'F', 'G'), ('H',), ('I', 'J', 'K')]` is correct, you can use a combination of `itertools.product` and `functools.reduce` to accomplish what you're looking for:

```
from functools import reduce
from itertools import product
comp = [('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), ('E', 'F', 'G'), ('H',), ('I', 'J', 'K')]
print(list(reduce(lambda a, b: [(*p[0], p[1]) for p in product(a, b)], comp)))
```

This outputs:

```
[('A', 'E', 'H', 'I'), ('A', 'E', 'H', 'J'), ('A', 'E', 'H', 'K'), ('A', 'F', 'H', 'I'), ('A', 'F', 'H', 'J'), ('A', 'F', 'H', 'K'), ('A', 'G', 'H', 'I'), ('A', 'G', 'H', 'J'), ('A', 'G', 'H', 'K'), ('B', 'E', 'H', 'I'), ('B', 'E', 'H', 'J'), ('B', 'E', 'H', 'K'), ('B', 'F', 'H', 'I'), ('B', 'F', 'H', 'J'), ('B', 'F', 'H', 'K'), ('B', 'G', 'H', 'I'), ('B', 'G', 'H', 'J'), ('B', 'G', 'H', 'K'), ('C', 'E', 'H', 'I'), ('C', 'E', 'H', 'J'), ('C', 'E', 'H', 'K'), ('C', 'F', 'H', 'I'), ('C', 'F', 'H', 'J'), ('C', 'F', 'H', 'K'), ('C', 'G', 'H', 'I'), ('C', 'G', 'H', 'J'), ('C', 'G', 'H', 'K'), ('D', 'E', 'H', 'I'), ('D', 'E', 'H', 'J'), ('D', 'E', 'H', 'K'), ('D', 'F', 'H', 'I'), ('D', 'F', 'H', 'J'), ('D', 'F', 'H', 'K'), ('D', 'G', 'H', 'I'), ('D', 'G', 'H', 'J'), ('D', 'G', 'H', 'K')]
```

But then given your first example of `[('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), ('E', 'F', 'I')]`, it would output the following instead:

```
[('A', 'E'), ('A', 'F'), ('A', 'I'), ('B', 'E'), ('B', 'F'), ('B', 'I'), ('C', 'E'), ('C', 'F'), ('C', 'I'), ('D', 'E'), ('D', 'F'), ('D', 'I')]
```

I'm assuming your second example is correct because the logic behind your first example simply wouldn't make sense when it scales to a length greater than 2.